# SDL Smart Target getting error while starting in browser?

Tags: smarttarget, fredhopper, sdl-tridion

[image]

I am getting above error while starting SDL SmartTarget 2011 SP1.
Please assist me..

Comment: Is your Fredhopper installed on the same server as Tridion/SmartTarget?

Comment: yeah...it is already installed

Comment: Is your fredhopperUrl correct in TRIDION_HOME\web\SmartTarget\smarttarget.xml ? And can you access that Url directly e.g. http://127.0.0.1:8180/fredhopper/admin/login.fh

Comment: i can't access it directly.

Comment: Please follow this part of the documentation: http://bit.ly/1NAYdrX you need to start the Fredhopper query server.

Comment: when i type startloader i am getting, Error:The system cannot find the path specified.
No universes given, and autodetection failed.
Please run this script from the base directory of your FAS installation!
Usage: startloader [-I instance] [universe...]

Comment: You need to run it from the Fredhopper root folder, not \bin.

Comment: What's the error in text? This can help others searching for the same issue or when Stack's image domain (imgur.com) is blocked.

Comment: But it is not available in fredhopper root folder.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error message is shown if it cannot connect to the Fredhopper URL configured in SmartTarget.xml (in TRIDION_HOME\web\SmartTarget).

So double-check that the URL is correct and that the Fredhopper instance is up and running.

Comment: i couldn't connect to fredhopper when i enter http://localhost:8180/fredhopper/admin/

Comment: You need to start the instance. See the following page in the documentation: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2011_SP1/task_C9747JJJFJF884JUJJJDE8E0E9

Comment: i have started through my command line but it giving the below error.

Comment: D:\fredhopper\instance01\FAS\bin>startloader
The system cannot find the path specified.
No universes given, and autodetection failed.
Please run this script from the base directory of
Usage: startloader [-I instance] [universe...]

Comment: As I commented on above, you need to run it from the FAS folder not the \bin folder.

Comment: when i run it from FAS folder then it gives this error;;;D:\fredhopper\instance01\FAS>startloader
'startloader' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: thanx all, i got the solution..

Comment: D:\fredhopper\instance01\FAS>bin\startloader.bat     is the correct way

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your fredhopper is stopped hence you are getting this error. 
Try after starting deployment agent and your indexer service.

Comment: which service i have to start plz suggest me.

Comment: for deployement agent type bin\deployment-agent from your fredhopper base directory. wait for around 90 sec andtype bin\instance <indexer> start in a new command prompt.